# Problem controlling SWF from javascript

Tags: javascript, flash

Quite simply, I have a SWF embedded in an HTML web page and want to move to a specific frame when a trigger is clicked.
But nothing happens when I click the trigger, as though the js just doesnt communicate at all with the swf.
SWF is written in flash cs4 (a3)
The link to the website is http://simplywebdzine.com/test.html.
I have read the text books over and over and researched high and wide on the internet and as far as I see I have done everything correctly but I cannot get this to work.
The swf is very basic, just a green box moving accross a small stage.
The desired gotoframe would make it cross at a lower height (just a dry run for a more complicated swf)

Would really appreciate someones help if you could possibly find out from the source code what is going wrong.
Many thanks
Steve

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you have two problems.

1. You do not have the correct id for your `<object>` according to your javascript.  The object id is "mymovi.swf" while your javascript is targeting "mymovi" as the id.
2. Even if I change your id using firebug, the function still does not fire off in the flash and I get an error about the function not existing.

Have you added a callback method in flash?  something like  `flash.external.ExternalInterface.addCallback("GotoFrame", gotoFrameHandler)` ??